# If $V$ is a vector space with inner product and $v\in\Lambda^p V$ and $w\in\Lambda^q V$, then $|v\wedge w|\le|v||w|$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we give $V$ an orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$, and let $v=\sum_I v_I e_I $ and $w=\sum_J w_J e_J$, then
\begin{align}
|v\wedge w|^2& =\left| \sum_{I,J}v_I w_J e_I\wedge e_J\right |^2
=\left| \sum_K \sum_{K=I\sqcup J} (\pm1)v_I w_J e_K\right |^2 \\
&\le \sum_K \left| \sum_{K=I\sqcup J} |v_I w_J| \right|^2 \\
&\le \sum_K\left( \sum_{I\subset K} |v_I|^2\right)
\left( \sum_{J\subset K} |w_J|^2\right)
\end{align}
which is unfortunately more than $|v|^2|w|^2$. Is there any way the statement can be salvaged?

Comment: I think the notation fails to make clear exactly what you are summing over; the outer sum is over $p+q$ sets $K$, but the inner one is over $p$-sets $I$ and by defintion $J=K\setminus I$ - as written it looks as though both sums are over $K$.

Comment: I don't get the first inequality: it seems to me to say that the square of a sum is less than the sum of squares.